# Обстоятельства времени и места

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли второе обстоятельство места уточняющим и нужна ли запятая, если два обстоятельства места разделены обстоятельством времени?

Потом списались и встретились на выставке (...) осенью 2014 года на конференции такой-то.

Comment: Уверен, что выделять запятыми не нужно, но аргументировать как следует не могу. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятую ставить не нужно. Это разные обстоятельства: времени и места.